# Assigning a JSON object to data field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am dynamically creating a row using javascript, here is the code below:

```
var row2 = "<tr><td><a href='#editModal' class='modal_trigger' data-info="+name+" data-toggle='modal'>Edit</a></td></tr>";
```

The var here is a JSON object. This is later passed onto the modal when a user clicks it and values can be retrieved. However, simply declaring `var` like I have done above sets `data-info=[Object object]`.

The content of the JSON variable is:

```
Object
  name: "Test 8"
  created_at: "2015-06-10 16:54:45"
  id: 128
  updated_at: "2015-06-10 16:54:45"
  __proto__: Object
```

Is there a way around it?

Comment: @kornieff, just tried: this leads to `data-info="{" "id":="" 6,=""...}`

Comment: what is the content of your `name` variable ? apparently it holds more than just a name. Add a `console.log(name)` right before your line of code, and tell us what gets printed on the console.

Comment: @LeGEC, posted the JSON Object

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify to put it in data object and then convert it back using JSON.parse when needed.

Comment: @Namit, what about data-info='{"id":"10"}'. Just use single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice here:

- Don't use `var` as a variable name, even in examples (real code won't even compile)
- Please, make sure you understand what JSON is, because Javascript object != JSON. Clearly `var` is a JS object in this case.

Said that, you can transform any JS object that does not contain functions into a JSON string with `JSON.stringify(variable)`:

UPDATE: This is what I mean:

```
var row2 = '<tr><td><a href="#editModal" class="modal_trigger" data-info="'+
        name+'" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a></td></tr>';
```

(Note the changes using quotation marks)

Comment: `var` was just used as an example here. Also, i have tried `JSON.stringify`, the result is: `data-info="{"id":7,"author_name":"Test" "User" ...}`

Comment: That's JSON!. Now you can create a JS object just making the opposite step: `JSON.parse(myJsonString)`

Comment: No, it accepts a JSON string, as I said, and returns a JS object

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. I already have an Object, using stringify produces the result - `data-info="{"id":7,"author_name":"Test" "User" ...}` which is incorrect.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? you cannot set a JS object as a tag's attribute's value, it must be a string

Comment: thanks for the update. Most of this is fine. However, values with spaces in them aren't being handled well by stringify. See the above example i.e. `"Test" "User"`, when it should be `"Test User"`

Answer (score 1):

If you get `[object Object]` then it is not a JSON, is an Object.
**[JSON](http://json.org/)** is a **string** containing an object serialized, and it is used as a lightweight data-interchange format.

Try serializing the object to JSON

```
"...data-info=" + JSON.stringify(myVar||null) + " data..."
```

Here I added coercion to `null` to prevent an error when the variable contains no data.

Comment: probably better to use `JSON.stringify(myVar || {})`

Comment: I have used `null` because if myVar is `undefined` or not contains data, when the [JSON](http://json.org/) is parsed to Object, it should reflect **empty data**, and the object `{}` is evaluated as `true` when is **coerced**, by contrast `null` does represent no data.

Comment: consider: `if ({}) //-> true`, instead: `if (null) //-> false`

Comment: Using `{}` avoids potential null reference errors down the road. (It really depends on what the OP is trying to do—he wasn't very clear.)

Comment: Yes, semantically, `null` represents no data, but for consistency and prevent **TypeError**, is a good way using an empty object `{}`.

Thanks for your advice @royhowie

Answer (score 0):

please Use `JSON.stringify(yourVar)`.

```
var row2 = "<tr><td><a href='#editModal' class='modal_trigger' data-info="+JSON.stringify(yourVar)+" data-toggle='modal'>Edit</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your `name` variables in some mapping or array, store the id or the index in your row, and use this to fetch it back later :

```
// using a mapping :
var infoMapping = {};

function createRow (name) {
    // this will work if 'id' is a key which identifies the object
    infoMapping[name.id] = name;
    var row2 = "<tr><td><a href='#editModal' ... data-infoid="+name.id+" ... ";
    // etc ...
}

function editModal (nRow) {
    var infoid = $(nRow).attr('data-infoid');
    var name = infoMapping[infoid];

    // use name ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little here.

Comment: @Namit : you mention some modal in your question, how do you use `data-info` in your modal ?

Comment: Once the modal is open, i am trying to access the object stored in `data-info`.

Comment: @Namit: the `data-info` attribute is a string. You could store the serialized version of your object there (as others have suggested), but you will need to somehow escape the `"` characters. Another way (which I suggest) is to store the object's id in `data-info`, and use this id to retrieve the object when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {a:10, b:20};
var html = "<div data-info='" + JSON.stringify(x) + "'></div>";
```

Result is

`"<div data-info='{"a":10,"b":20}'></div>"`